# Square root algorithm in C

Tags: c, algorithm, square-root

For practicing reasons I coded the following algorithm in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(){

double x=0;

printf("Enter the number: ");

scanf("%lf", &x);

int i = 0;

double v = 0;
double n=0;
int grenze = 12;
double z = 10;
/*
for(i=1; i<(x/2+1); i++){
    v=i;
    if((v*v) <= x){
        n = i;
    }
}

v=n;
*/
for(i=1; i<grenze+1; i++){
    z = z * 0.1;

    while(v*v<x){
        v = v + z;
        if(v*v<x){
            n = v;
        }
    }
    v=n;
}
printf("%.10f\n", n);



}
```

This works quite well, but for number greater than a certain value (I do not know when this starts) for example 50.000.000.000 the program freezes.

Is there anything I do not see here?

Comment: Have you used a debugger to help you? It's designed exactly to help for delving into such problems.

Comment: Oh could it be that the first iteration of the for loop is just too large so it freezes?

Comment: @kaylum No I did not use a debugger. I am currently writing code in vim in the terminal.

Comment: What does that have to do with using a debugger? A debugger (ie, gdb) can run in the terminal.

Comment: For a big enough number, `v = v + z;` is a no-op — `v` doesn't change.  That makes your loop run for a long time.  The algorithm is not a good choice.  I'm not convinced it will work well for numbers like `1E-70` (and you've shown it won't work for numbers like `1E+70`).  Note that doubles have a range up to `1E±300` or more on most machines with IEEE floating point math support.

Comment: @kaylum thank you for clarifying me, I thought that it would need an IDE. I will look for that.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you for your explanation. But could you maybe explain why for a certain limit v = v + z is a no-op please?

Comment: Floating point numbers have a finite number of decimal digits — around about 16 for `double`, usually.  If you add `1E+16` and `1E-16`, then the result is `1E+16`; there aren't enough significant digits to store the extra information.  You have `5E+10` as the start point; you generate fractions `z = 1.0` then `0.1`, `0.01`, ... `0.000 000 000 01` or thereabouts (what's an order of magnitude between friends?).  When you go around adding the smallest values, you don't end up changing anything.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you very much! Now I do understand this. Can I somehow give you the "you answered this" mark?

Comment: The canonical document on the subject is [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) or from the [ACM](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=103163).  And there should be a Q&A for which this can be a duplicate.  I don't have it identified yet.  I'll transfer my comments into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a big enough number `v` and small enough number `z`, `v = v + z`; is a no-op — `v` doesn't change. That makes your loop run for a long time.

The algorithm is not a good choice — you should look up the [Newton-Raphson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method) method. I'm not convinced your algorithm will work well for extreme numbers like `1E-70` (and you've shown it won't work for numbers like `1E+70`). Note that doubles have a range up to 1E±300 or more on most machines with IEEE floating point support.

> Could you maybe explain why for a certain limit `v = v + z` is a no-op please?

Floating point numbers have a finite number of decimal digits — around about 16 for double, usually. If you add `1E+16` and `1E-16`, then the result is `1E+16`; there aren't enough significant digits to store the extra information. You have `5E+10` as the start point; you generate fractions `z = 1.0` then `0.1`, `0.01`, … `0.000 000 000 01` or thereabouts (what's an order of magnitude between friends?). When you go around adding the smallest values, you don't end up changing anything.

The canonical document on the subject is [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) or from the [ACM](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=103163).

Answer (score 0):

If you write a `printf` statement in the while loop to show you `v`, you will see that at some point it stops changing (which is bad, because you use it to exit your loop!).

I put `printf("DEBUG: entered for loop, v=%lf\n", v);` in the while loop and saw this:

```
DEBUG: entered for loop, v=173205.080757
DEBUG: entered for loop, v=173205.080757
DEBUG: entered for loop, v=173205.080757
DEBUG: entered for loop, v=173205.080757
DEBUG: entered for loop, v=173205.080757
DEBUG: entered for loop, v=173205.080757
DEBUG: entered for loop, v=173205.080757
DEBUG: entered for loop, v=173205.080757
```

You were adding z which is so small that when v is at 173205 it doesn't actually change the value. You can extend the range by changing the type of `v` to `long double`; however, as we only have a certain number of bits to work with, there is still an upper bound where adding a small enough number to it won't change the representable value.

Comment: Changing to `long double` is a temporary band aid — change the source number from 5E10 to 5E50 and `long double` will be no help.  It also won't resolve the problems for tiny source numbers.

Comment: Very true Jonathan, and I quickly edited it to reflect that reality.